# How can I put featured results above non featured in my results list?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, wordpress-featured-image

This code from `loop-ad_listing.php` is what makes all the post results appear in a list. But now I want to put featured posts above the non featured (order = featured, then non featured). What code do I need to put in this code so that featured posts appear first?

Any help appreciated :)

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>">


    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true) )
            $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);
        else
            $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);
        ?>

        <div id="post-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-wrapper">

            <div class="post-block">
                <?php if ( is_sticky() ) echo '<strong>FEATURED</strong>'; ?>

             <div class="grid_100">
             <?php if ( get_option('cp_ad_images') == 'yes' ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="post-desc">
        <?php echo $make_address; ?>
                    <div class="post-debug">

                        <!--<h4>Description:</h4>
                        <?php echo cp_get_content_preview( 160 ); ?>--!>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /post-block -->
        </div><!-- /post-wrapper -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /page --> 

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="block"><center>Sorry, no results found...</center></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to before your Loop to `orderby` the `meta_value` using the specified `meta_key`. This assumes that `cp_ad_featured_thumbnail` is not set for un-featured posts.

```
<?php
$args = array( "orderby"=>"meta_value", "meta_key"=>"cp_ad_featured_thumbnail" );
query_posts( $args );
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> 
<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>"> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- POST CONTENT -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: I pasted it as follows (is this right?): 

 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>">

  
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $args = array( "orderby"=>"meta_value", "meta_key"=>"cp_ad_featured_thumbnail" );?>

Comment: it has to go outside of The Loop, so before the call to `have_posts()`. Check out my edits.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but it didn't work. I think I didn't give you enough information. I have edited the original question.

Comment: I did a quick search for the source of that function, and it's not immediately obvious what would determine that a post has or does not have a featured ad... sorry.

Comment: Posts are called ads on my website. A featured ad is the same as a sticky post - Wordpress. At the moment the post list contains all posts, but the featured are not coming first.

Comment: I think this kind of thing needs to be included somewhere: 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' =>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
<!-- display all post (exclude non-sticky post) -->
query_posts(array("post__in"=>get_option("sticky_posts")));

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>">


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true) )
        $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);
    else
        $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);
    ?>

    <div id="post-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-wrapper">

        <div class="post-block">
          <?php echo '<strong>FEATURED</strong>'; ?>
          <div class="grid_100">
          <?php if ( get_option('cp_ad_images') == 'yes' ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

            <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="post-desc">
          <?php echo $make_address; ?>
            <div class="post-debug">
              <!--<h4>Description:</h4>
              <?php echo cp_get_content_preview( 160 ); ?>--!>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /post-block -->
    </div><!-- /post-wrapper -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /page --> 

<?php endif; ?>    
<?php 
<!-- display all post (exclude non-sticky post) -->
query_posts(array("post__not_in"=>get_option("sticky_posts")));

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>">


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true) )
        $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);
    else
        $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);
    ?>

    <div id="post-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-wrapper">

        <div class="post-block">

          <div class="grid_100">
          <?php if ( get_option('cp_ad_images') == 'yes' ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

            <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="post-desc">
          <?php echo $make_address; ?>
            <div class="post-debug">
              <!--<h4>Description:</h4>
              <?php echo cp_get_content_preview( 160 ); ?>--!>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /post-block -->
    </div><!-- /post-wrapper -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /page --> 

<?php else: ?>

<div class="block"><center>Sorry, no results found...</center></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are syntax errors. This was caused by the comments. I moved them outside the php tags so the syntax errors went away. The sort order has not been fixed. There are 25,500 files in my website, so maybe there's something overriding this - or its incorrect.